# Any creative ways to add rank ordering numbering to this simple sortable package example?

Tags: html, r, shiny, ranking, sortablejs

I am trying to rank order number the list elements in the “Drag to” panel on the right when running the below "Reproducible Code". See image at the bottom for an illustration.

I found an example, [Add index to sortable object text in R Sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60880078/add-index-to-sortable-object-text-in-r-sortable), where list elements are rank order numbered using HTML with the same sortable package. However, this example uses sortable's `bucket_list()` and `add_rank_list()` and that html snippet only works in conjunction with those functions. For “cloning” reasons I’m using `sortable_js()` instead of `bucket_list()` and `add_rank_list()`.

How can I add rank order numbers to those list elements?

**Reproducible Code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)
library(htmlwidgets)

icons <- function(x) {lapply(x,function(x){tags$div(tags$strong(x))})}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  div(
    style = "margin-top: 2rem; width: 60%; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; gap: 2rem; align-items: start;",

    div(
      div(
        class = "panel panel-default",
        div(class = "panel-heading", "Drag from here"),
        div(
          class = "panel-body",
          id = "drag_from",
          icons(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
        )
      ),
    ),
    div(
      div(
        class = "panel panel-default",
        div(class = "panel-heading", "Drag to here"),
        div(
          class = "panel-body",
          id = "drag_to"
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  sortable_js(
    "drag_from",
    options = sortable_options(
      group = list(
        pull = "clone",
        name = "group1",
        put = FALSE
      )
    )
  ),
  sortable_js(
    "drag_to",
    options = sortable_options(
      group = list(
        group = "group1",
        put = TRUE,
        pull = TRUE
      ),
      onAdd = htmlwidgets::JS() # something that works here to rank order number to each element dragged in?
    )
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Illustration:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only target the display format, you could [include some custom CSS](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) to [enumerate the CSS-selected elements](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/numbering-with-css-counters/) like so:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
         tags$style(HTML('
             #drag_to {list-style-type: none;  counter-reset: css-counter 0;}
             #drag_to > div {counter-increment: css-counter 1;}
             #drag_to > div:before {content: counter(css-counter) ". ";}
      ')
      )
      ) ##, etc.
```

I'd also suggest you choose a cursor style which signals a draggable item (currently you're using one for text input). Add this to above CSS declarations if desired:

```
    #drag_from > div {cursor: move; #fallback
                      cursor: grab; cursor: -moz-grab;
                      cursor: -webkit-grab;
                      }
```

Comment: That works very nicely, thank you! I've been stuck deep into this, searching and researching with no luck for days. You have completely bailed me out of the ditch. HTML/CSS is very new to me and not so easy to learn.

Comment: Maybe CSS wouldn't have come into my mind, hadn't I needed to do some CSS fiddling right before your question popped up. Guess that sort of anchored me :-)